# Send data to c++ application to Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, sockets, ipc

Hello I'm working on a Kinect Application and I need to send the data generated by the Kinect to Matlab.

I transfer the data succesfully by pipes but is not as fast as it should be after 10 minutes (don't know why) so I need to use Sockets.
I need to send the coordenates 'xr' and 'yr'.

How can I implement a Socket in my app and in Matlab?

```
SingleFace* pApp = reinterpret_cast<SingleFace*>(pVoid);
if (pApp)
{
    IFTResult* pResult = pApp->m_FTHelper.GetResult();
    if (pResult && SUCCEEDED(pResult->GetStatus()))
    {
        AllocConsole();
        freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
        freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

        FLOAT* pAU = NULL;
        UINT numAU;
        pResult->GetAUCoefficients(&pAU, &numAU);
        pApp->m_eggavatar.SetCandideAU(pAU, numAU);
        FLOAT scale;
        FLOAT rotationXYZ[3];
        FLOAT translationXYZ[3];
        pResult->Get3DPose(&scale, rotationXYZ, translationXYZ);
        pApp->m_eggavatar.SetTranslations(translationXYZ[0], translationXYZ[1], translationXYZ[2]);
        pApp->m_eggavatar.SetRotations(rotationXYZ[0], rotationXYZ[1], rotationXYZ[2]);
        // OUTPUT WINDOW
        std::string resultados = "T = [" + to_string(translationXYZ[0]) + "," + to_string(translationXYZ[1]) + "," + to_string(translationXYZ[2]) + ", ], R=[" + to_string(rotationXYZ[0]) + "," + to_string(rotationXYZ[0]) + "," + to_string(rotationXYZ[1]) + "," + to_string(rotationXYZ[2]) + "], sc=" + to_string(scale) + "/n";
        std::wstring stemp = s2ws(resultados);
        LPCWSTR results = stemp.c_str();
        OutputDebugStringW(results);

        /*Matrix to calculate the real coordenates
        A1 = 98.1987    4.8642
             -6.3882   79.6357
              9.9648   20.0521*/

        int xr =98.1987*translationXYZ[0] - 6.3882*translationXYZ[2] + 9.9648;
        int yr = 4.8642*translationXYZ[0] + 79.6357*translationXYZ[2] + 20.0521;
        //Real Tracking Points
        cout << "(" << xr << "," << yr << ")\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a precise solution but I'd start looking here:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html

to start figuring out how to do the matlab server side, then you could leverage some TCP/IP library in windows (I'm not too familiar with programming windows applications).

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, the main problem is how to send the data, thanks to your link I'm able to receive it.